# NODE 8.0.0 and NPM 4.2.0 ERROR express-load require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm

I am creating an app in Node 8.0.0 and NPM 5.0.0 and when i using express-load `var load = require("express-load");` my server returns:

```
load/lib/express-load.js:32

  if (require.extensions.hasOwnProperty(ext) && extlist.indexOf(ext) === -1) {
                         ^

TypeError: require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/node_modules/express-load/lib/express-load.js:32:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/node_modules/express-load/index.js:8:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
```

I tried downgrade to npm `sudo npm install -g npm@4.2.0` version 4.2.0 (https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates/issues/355) and does not works

This post [npm check updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates/issues/361) works to me.

thanks!!!!

Comment: try this command npm uninstall npm-check-updates -g && npm install npm-check-updates -g

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `node_module/` folder of your project and make a again `npm install`. It works for me.

Comment: Did that, no luck my friend

Answer (score 18):

None of the answers posted so far explain why the issue happens and how to fix it.

### The Scoop

In Node 6 `require.extensions` was initialized with `{}`. In Node 8, it is initialized with `Object.create(null)`.

A test like

```
if (require.extensions.hasOwnProperty(ext) {
```

cannot work in Node 8 and higher due to the way `require.extensions` is initialized with `Object.create(null)`. (Details below.)

The code above has to become:

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(require.extensions, ext)) {
```

You still have to use `hasOwnProperty` for compatibility with Node 6. Once compatibility with 6 is dropped, it could be reduced to `if (ext in require.extensions) {` because the distinction between own and inherited properties is meaningless for objects created by `Object.create(null)`.

**If the faulty code is your own,** just make the change.

**If the faulty code is not your own**, then upgrading the package you are using may fix the issue if the devs already took care of fixing the problem. If the problem persists in the latest version of the package, then you need to put in an issue report explaining the problem so that the maintainers fix their code.

### Additional Details

What has changed from version 6 to version 8 is the way `require.extensions` is created.

**Version 6**: `require.extensions` gets its value from `Module._extensions`. ([Here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.11.2/lib/internal/module.js#L35).) And `Module._extensions` is initialized [as follows](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.11.2/lib/module.js#L53):

```
Module._extensions = {};
```

**Version 8**: `require.extensions` gets is value from `Module._extensions`. ([Here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/7e3a3c962f09233c53cee7ebe381341d7c8b7162/lib/internal/module.js#L26).) And `Module._extensions` is initialized  [as follows](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/7e3a3c962f09233c53cee7ebe381341d7c8b7162/lib/module.js#L66):

```
Module._extensions = Object.create(null);
```

Now run the following code:

```
// This is fine.
console.log({}.hasOwnProperty("foo"));

// This will fail.
console.log(Object.create(null).hasOwnProperty("foo"));
```

An object created with `Object.create(null)` does not have the `hasOwnProperty` method. In fact an object newly created with `Object.create(null)` has no property whatsoever defined on it, because it does not inherit from anything. This is the appeal of such objects because then you don't have to worry about own properties and inherited properties. `"toString" in {}` is true because it is inherited from `Object` whereas `"toString" in Object.create(null)` is false.

If you want to use `hasOwnProperty` on it, most likely for compatibility with older versions that may initialize an object you don't control, you have to acquire the method from the `Object` class:

```
const obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "foo"));
```

Answer (score 15):

I had this error with `require-dir@0.3.1`. Upgrading to 0.3.2 solved my problem.

Comment: The current gulp-svn version 1.0.8 uses an old version of require-dir. Replacing the folder "node_modules\gulp-svn\node_modules\require-dir" with the new version did the trick for me. Also see https://github.com/yasinkocak/gulp-svn/issues/6

Comment: worked for me as well for an old ionic v1 project with node 11

Answer (score 6):

This is not an npm issue, and strictly a node.js issue.

`require.extensions` has been [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions) since node v0.10.6 and upgrading to node 8, which fully drops support for it, causes that error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was **gulp-svn**. It has an embedded version of *require-dir* in its own *npm_modules* folder, which is outdated. I had to replace `../node_modules/gulp-svn/node_modules/require-dir` with the latest *require-dir*.

I got this answer from [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2876079/stefan) in one of the comments above.